# Rollback Procedure in XM Cloud for Production Environment

Tags: xm-cloud

To facilitate the deployment of our upcoming releases within the XM Cloud environment (on the production environment), I'm seeking guidance on the process of rolling back to a previous version in the event of a critical issue.

Is there a backup mechanism in place within XM Cloud that allows us to restore to a previous state? Alternatively, could anyone provide instructions or recommendations for executing a rollback procedure?

Thank you.
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the deploy app and redeploy a previous version from there.

You are not able to restore a backup of the CM instance.

If you rollback the CM, make sure you deploy the matching version of your Next.js application to your host

Comment: Hello @Richard Seal,

Thank you for your informative response. I am currently utilizing Vercel as the Rendering Host. In the event of redeploying a previous version (using git tag version), I have a concern regarding the content created by Content Authors. Should we clean up this content, or is it advisable to leave it as is?

Appreciate your guidance on this matter.

Comment: I assume that you are using Sitecore Serialization to serialize the content so you can use that. https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/create-and-install-a-sitecore-content-serialization-package.html

Comment: The content is the content, if the rollback removes fields from a template, that content will effectively be removed. There could be some potential issues if a field type has changed, but in reality - if you have to rollback a version, you know about it pretty quickly. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks @AmitKumar, I can create package to backup content before deploy.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSeal, Great! It is make sense. I will leave content there.

Comment: @NathanNgo if this answer helped, please mark it as accepted to help others in the future. Thanks